# MyFirstApp Android Studio 'Default Activity not found'/'Unused Import directive (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio

I did the myfirstapp tutorial from developer.android.com, see here: [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#run).
I'm using Android Studio 3.5.2.
I'm a complete beginner so takes a bit of time finding my way through all the menus. I managed up to 'Build a simple user interface' and actually understand what happens/need to be done.
I can follow the instructions for 'Start another activity'. Modify the code for the MainActivity like this:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = editText.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Then I create a second activity. First I create the window, then modify the code as follow

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
            text = message
        }
    }
}
```

The tutorial states that I need the following imports:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
```

However, only the last 2 show up. If I add the first 2 manually, it gives the message 'Unused import directive'?

I also get the message for setContentView, findViewById and text that they are 'Unresolved reference'.

If I want to run the app I get the message: 'Default Activity not found'

Not sure if this is all related, but I wonder how to proceed. If I press Alt+Enter at 'intent' to import it's class it doesn't give me that option, I can create a local variable, parameter or property. Same for the others.

@Bracadabra 
The manifest file looks like this, I did add the activity:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity2"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

@Md.Assaduzzaman I did forget the first line of code for the DisplayMessageActivity, I've included it now and it activates the `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`
but not the `import android.content.Intent`

The error message is still the same.

Comment: Post your `DisplayMessageActivity` in detail

Answer (score 1):

Please, check your AndroidManifest file, your activity should be declare in it. Something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import the Intent class and the TextView class because you currently are not using either in your second Activity.

the line `intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)` refers to the getIntent method attached to an activity.

You would need to import those classes when you want to instantiate them for use in your activity.

I hope this helps

Comment: In the tutorial they write that an intent is build by adding the EXTRA_MESSAGE constant and the sendMessage code, by adding the following code to MainActivity: which I have done (see above).

Answer (score 0):

rai kavadia and Bracadabra put me on the right track. The mainActivity wasn't declared in the AndroidManifest file. In the end all worked well like this.

The MainActivity kotlin file:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = editText.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

The DisplayMessageActivity Kotlin file:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.mysecondapp.R.layout.activity_display_message
import android.widget.TextView

class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(activity_display_message)

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
            text = message
        }
    }
}
```

The AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```